# Ethernet communication via Raspberry3

Tags: raspberry-pi, ethernet, microphones

I recently used an IP-camera to monitor my garden. Now I want to expand with various sensors and a microphone module. Therefore I would use an Raspberry, the camera for the Pi and an USB microphone. The  other pins are used for the sensors.

My problem is the communication with my with the PI. I would like to view and hear a live feed and also occasionally send status data (small ASCII file).

Since the PI has an Ethernet port, is it possible to send a live audio/video feed and data via cable (20m)? Is there a Linux based program to achieve this or do I need additional hardware/cabling?

Comment: you can certainly do that but... - your question is very broad. We could write a book about that and a good part of it would involve just exploring the various possibilities and your needs. - I doubt this really belongs to iot. There's a dedicated [raspberry pi exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) but what you are asking really includes a lot of stuff such as LAN systems, some linux programming, a bit of software engineering. Try splitting your question in various steps. You already know LAN is used to transfer files so it can be done. To transfer a file SSH could be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

As @MaxDZ8 says, your question is very broad, but I'd like to encourage you, and this is something I'm also interested in.

You should start small, perhaps with a simple system.

You've mentioned an IP-camera, and the Pi 3 can certainly do that, for example:

[Build a Raspberry Pi Webcam Server in Minutes](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-webcam-server/)

(see Setting up outside External Access)

Regarding your specific questions:

a) Since the PI has an Ethernet port, is it possible to send a live audio/video feed and data via cable (20m)?

- Ethernet range can be up to 100m, but how about trying WiFi which the Pi 3 has?

b) Is there a Linux based program to achieve this or do I need additional hardware/cabling?

- The link abouve mentions something to get you started. In time you're sure to start accumulating more hardware.